# There are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 7 (\text{mod} \ 8).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

There are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 7 \ (\text{mod} \ 8).$

I have just started to learn elementary number theory. May I know if my proof to the a/m problem is correct? Please advise, thank you.

Proof:
Suppose there are finitely many such primes. Let $N = (p_1p_2...p_k)^2-2,$ where $p1,...,p_k \equiv 7\ (\text{mod} \ 8).$

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $N.$ Then, $(p_1...p_k)^2 \equiv 2  \ (\text{mod} \ p).$ Hence, $2$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $\Big(\frac{2}{p}\Big)=1 \implies p \equiv 1 \ \text{or} \ 7 \ (\text{mod} \ 8).$

If all prime divisors of $N$ are $\equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 8),$ then $N \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ 8).$

On other hand, since $(p_1)^2,...,(p_k)^2 \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ 8), $ it follows that $N=(p_1...p_k)^2 -2 \equiv -1 \equiv 7 \ (\text{mod} \ 8).$ Hence, there exists a prime divisor $q \equiv 7\ (\text{mod} \ 8)$

Then, $q \mid (p_1...p_k)^2$ and $q \mid N \implies q \mid 2.$ (Contradiction).

Comment: Yep, nice proof I think!

Comment: You probably have seen Dirichlet theorem on primes produced by arithmetic progression. A00522 sequence is for primes of form $8 n+7$ which are infinitely many.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinitely many prime divisors of $f(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682845) Your proof is the particular case $f(x)=x^2-2.$